# Android programming use of alarmmanger

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to show toast at a specific time using AlarmManger but my toast is not shown at given time? Help me.
My code is as follows:

```
private void startAlarm() {
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,9);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,7);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,2);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,55);
    cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: Do you have a `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: You need to show the code for the intent you're trying to start. It seems to be `WelcomActivity`, which looks like it is an `Activity`, but then you get an `PendingIntent` for a broadcast `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`, that won't work. Also you're saying a `Toast` isn't shown. The only `Toast` in the code you posted is shown directly after calling `setInexactRepeating`, which is when it would be appearing. It is not part of the activity/broadcast you're trying to start.

Comment: how to declare broadcast receiver in menifest file
i have error in receiver tag am using android atudio
<receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </receiver>

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) for `setInexactRepeating` states:

> Your alarm's first trigger will not be before the requested time, but it might not occur for almost a full interval after that time.

[edit thanks to ci_]

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your
>   application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time
>   exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy
>   applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will
>   continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms,
>   treated as exact.

So you need to use one-time exact alarms and reschedule as described in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

Comment: Read the docs you linked again: "Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above."

Comment: Darn - I will edit my answer. Thanks for the correction!